# StackOverflowError while gradle build

Tags: java, gradle

I am facing following exception while building a gradle project. (Note that I have trimmed the stacktrace to avoid clutter. But the actual stack is much longer with repetitive calls.)

```
17:28:15.884 [ERROR] [system.err] The system is out of resources.
17:28:15.885 [ERROR] [system.err] Consult the following stack trace for details.
17:28:15.885 [ERROR] [system.err] java.lang.StackOverflowError
17:28:15.886 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.readToken(JavaTokenizer.java:538)
17:28:15.886 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.nextToken(Scanner.java:115)
17:28:15.886 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.nextToken(JavacParser.java:301)
17:28:15.886 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.arguments(JavacParser.java:1816)
17:28:15.886 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.arguments(JavacParser.java:1833)
17:28:15.886 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1294)
17:28:15.887 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:909)
17:28:15.887 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:880)
17:28:15.887 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:836)
17:28:15.887 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:816)
17:28:15.887 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseExpression(JavacParser.java:779)
17:28:15.887 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parExpression(JavacParser.java:2299)
17:28:15.888 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2483)
17:28:15.888 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
17:28:15.888 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java:2337)
17:28:15.888 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2308)
17:28:15.888 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2322)
17:28:15.888 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2480)
17:28:15.888 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
17:28:15.889 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2356)
17:28:15.889 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2484)
17:28:15.889 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2391)
17:28:15.889 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java:2337)
17:28:15.889 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2308)
17:28:15.889 [ERROR] [system.err]       at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2322)
```

I have found the value of `ThreadStackSize` option by firing following command:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize
```

The output is as follows:

```
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 320                                 {pd product}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 512                                 {pd product}
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

How can I approach the root cause behind this issue or what could be possible work around?

Comment: What task are you running? Just `build`? Post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: What code are you trying to compile?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the stack size e.g. by adding `-Xss1024k` to command line arguments. As long as this not a recursion problem in `JavacParser` increasing the stack size should do the trick.